# How to svn merge branch to trunk including both file deletes and file adds?

Tags: svn, merge

Use of "svn merge --reintegrate" successfully merged branch back to trunk with regards to branch files deleted being deleted on the trunk as well. This is what I expected and wanted. Good.

However it did not add files to trunk that were added on the branch.  While "svn merge --reintegrate" **copied** the added file to the trunk working directory they were not added to svn and of course were not committed.  I did not expect this.  Bad.

How can I safely merge branch to trunk changes including file deletes and file adds?

**Here Is What I Did**

The my-bug-fix branch was created from the last official release on the trunk.  This is a single developer project but I still managed to mess up the merge and break the build.

Before merging I checked out both branch and trunk into a "staging" folder to make it easy to a diff.  I was hoping the diff would assure me the merge was what I expected before committing. Unfortunately diff had no knowledge that the added file had not been added to svn.

```
mkdir merge-staging
cd merge-staging
svn co https://myserver.com:8443/svn/myproject/branches/my-bug-fix/ branch
svn co https://myserver.com:8443/svn/myproject/trunk/ trunk
cd trunk
svn merge --reintegrate https://myserver.com:8443/svn/myproject/branches/my-bug-fix/
echo Perform diff between branch and trunk to verify the trunk now matches branch.
diff -r  --exclude=".svn" branch/ trunk/

svn --version
svn, version 1.6.15 (r1038135)
   compiled Nov 25 2010, 00:08:34

[esutton@esutton-vm-rhel merge]$ svn status trunk
X       trunk/common/externals
?       trunk/common/scripts/strip-dbg-sym.sh
```

Thanks in advance for any direction,
-Ed

Answer (score 1):

1. If `merge --reintegrate`, why I can't see merged trunk to my-bug-fix branch before it?
2. Why I can't see real output of commands?
3. Why I can't see your `svn --version`?
4. Why I can't see 'svn log -v -q' for your repo for rev-in-question?
5. `svn status` instead of diff will be usable

Back to problem:

I can't confirm or reproduce described effect

```
>svn log -v file:///Z:/Repo
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r9 | Badger | 2013-04-23 07:32:26 +0600 (Вт, 23 апр 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk
   M /trunk/fleA.txt
   D /trunk/fleB.txt
   A /trunk/fleC.txt (from /branches/corrections/fleC.txt:8)

Reintegrated branch to trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r8 | Badger | 2013-04-23 07:30:04 +0600 (Вт, 23 апр 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /branches/corrections
   M /branches/corrections/fleA.txt

Merged trunk to branches/corrections
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r7 | Badger | 2013-04-23 07:25:40 +0600 (Вт, 23 апр 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   D /branches/corrections/fleB.txt

Deleted fleB.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r6 | Badger | 2013-04-23 07:24:57 +0600 (Вт, 23 апр 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/corrections/fleC.txt

Added fleC.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r5 | Badger | 2013-04-23 07:23:37 +0600 (Вт, 23 апр 2013) | 2 lines
Changed paths:
   M /branches/corrections/fleA.txt

Added string to fleA.txt

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4 | Badger | 2013-04-23 07:22:12 +0600 (Вт, 23 апр 2013) | 2 lines
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/fleA.txt

Edited fleA.txt

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | Badger | 2013-04-23 07:20:25 +0600 (Вт, 23 апр 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/corrections (from /trunk:2)

Branch for changes
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | Badger | 2013-04-23 07:17:25 +0600 (Вт, 23 апр 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/fleA.txt
   A /trunk/fleB.txt

Starting point
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | Badger | 2013-04-23 07:15:06 +0600 (Вт, 23 апр 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches
   A /tags
   A /trunk

Imported folder structure
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
>svn ls -v file:///Z:/Repo/trunk
      9 Badger                апр 23 07:32 ./
      9 Badger             52 апр 23 07:32 fleA.txt
      9 Badger             40 апр 23 07:32 fleC.txt
```

Comment: Since you can not reproduce I assume it is a glitch.  I think for now on I will run "svn status" before I commit the merge and look for added files that have not been committed.  "svn status trunk |grep ^\?"